# Get a WebMethod to be enacted from an Ajax Command

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

How do I get a WebMethod to be enacted from an Ajax Command?

When I click Button1 I get the Error Code on the Alert saying:

```
"Error Code: [object Object]"
```

Default.aspx:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetDateTime() {
        var jsonid = $("#<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>").val();
        var json1 = "{'id':'" + jsonid + "'}";
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetServerDateTime",
            data: json1,
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.d);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("Error Code: " + err);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "scr", "Javascript:GetDateTime();", true);
    }
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetServerDateTime(string id)
    {
        string datetimeid1 = "ID: " + id + " Date&Time" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
        return datetimeid1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting a `500 Internal Server Error` due to improper JSON. You can properly encode JSON with `JSON.stringify`, so change this:

```
var json1 = "{'id':'" + jsonid + "'}";
```

to this:

```
var json1 = JSON.stringify({ id: jsonid });
```